Counting grades of 'A' but returning all records
I am trying to figure out a query in SQL Server where I have two tables, Grades & Courses. The query needs to return all the courses with a total count of students that received an 'A' for the quarter. Them result set should look like this:
   Course Title          Number of A's
       Math                    1
     Science                   0
     Geography                 4
     Economics                 0
   World History               2

I can get the query to return three of those rows...the ones with A's but not other grades. The courses with 0 are obviously the ones where no A's were passed out but they need to be included in the query.
This is my query below:your text
SELECT A.Title
    COUNT(B.Grades) AS [Number of A''s]
FROM Courses A 
LEFT JOIN on Grades B ON A.Course_ID = B.Course_ID
WHERE B.Grades = 'A'
GROUP BY B.Grades, A.Title
ORDER BY A.Course_ID


If this is SQL Server, why do you tag your question with MySQL???

If you want to see courses without grade, you use LEFT JOIN
SELECT A.Title, B.Grade, COUNT(*) AS TheCount
FROM Courses A 
LEFT JOIN on Grades B ON A.Course_ID = B.Course_ID AND B.Grades = 'A'
GROUP BY B.Grades, A.Title
ORDER BY A.Course_ID


Put the Grade='A' criteria on the join instead of within the WHERE clause
SELECT A.Title,
       COUNT(B.Grade) AS [Number of As]
FROM Courses A 
LEFT JOIN Grades B ON A.Course_ID = B.Course_ID AND B.Grade = 'A'
--WHERE  B.Grade = 'A'  
GROUP BY B.Grade, A.Title
ORDER BY min(A.Course_ID)

fiddle



Title
NumberOfAs




Math
2


Science
0


Geography
0


Economics
1


World History
0



